# routing multiple IPs on a single bond device - debian linux

Tags: networking, nginx, debian, routing, iproute2

I'm using linux server with nginx and additional IP-addresses for various web-sites.
It has main eth0 device with ipv4 (xx.xxx.210.245) and ipv6 (xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:ffff:6189:d2f5) and bond0 (xx.xxx.92.134), bond0:1 (xxx.xxx.22.68), bond0:2 (xx.xxx.39.43). bond0:3 (xxx.xxx.11.118) and etc devices with additional IPs assigned to them. IPs are from various locations, not from one subnet. My websites are available from internet by this IPs and all of them have their own domain names.

The problem is that if I'll check the outgoing IPs with php and curl like this:

```
<?php
//$ch = curl_init('http://whatismyip.org/'); // ipv6
$ch = curl_init('http://ipinfo.io/ip'); // ipv4
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
$myIp = curl_exec($ch);
echo $myIp;
?>
```

, then it I will see my **main server IPv4** in each ipv4 check (via ipinfo.io/ip) and **main server IPv6** in each ipv6 check (via whatismyip.org). And it happens with every domain on additional IPv4 that I have.

How to configure such a network with multiple IPs, so it will be possible to keep all outgoing connections through each of this IPs?
So if I will make mentioned curl php check on bond0:2 (xx.xxx.39.43) or bond0:3 (xxx.xxx.11.118), then I will have their IPs in both ipv4 check (via ipinfo.io/ip) and ipv6 check (via whatismyip.org)?

**Additional infofmation:**

`route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         xx.xxx.210.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

xxx.xxx.11.118  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0

xx.xxx.210.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

`ip rule list`

```
0:      from all lookup local

32764:  from all to xxx.xxx.11.118 lookup outgoing

32765:  from xxx.xxx.11.118 lookup outgoing

32766:  from all lookup main

32767:  from all lookup default
```

I've added 2 rules for bond0:3 (xxx.xxx.11.118) that is in `outgoing` table with this commands:

```
ip rule add from xxx.xxx.11.118/32 table outgoing
ip rule add to xxx.xxx.11.118/32 outgoing
```

And I also made this:

```
ip route add xxx.xxx.11.0/24 dev bond0:3 src xxx.xxx.11.118 table outgoing
```

But it doesn't help to reach outgoing connections via xxx.xxx.11.118 and **NOT main server IP**.

*It's pity to notice that there is no similar questions/answers like in my topic, so I can't find the way how to get it work..
Thanks for any help!*

**EDIT:**

I've found that this is specific problem of my server's Data Center - my support told that it's may be only possible to fix that, if we will bing mac-addresses for each additional IP, but after that connection breaks and reboot in recovery are possible.
I think it's not safe way, so I decided not to use it and find something more stable and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution how to set up linux server or services, but I can't find it. Feel free to add your answer - I will be very grateful!

After some time I've found how to solve it inside php itself, since I've discovered the problem after using curl in php.

**1.** Using `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` parameter in [`curl_setopt` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with `$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]` value:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_INTERFACE,$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]);
```

After adding this line to curl code it will use your server's ip-address in outgoing request.
**Attention!** It may not work on all setups and operating systems!
But it worked for me on Debian Wheezy with nginx and php-fpm 5.4.45 and I believe it should work on major linux systems with php > 5.3 or even earlier.

**2.** Using context options and bind server's ip in socket options.

```
$opts['socket'] = array('bindto' => $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].':0');
$context = stream_context_create($opts); 
echo file_get_contents('http://whatismyip.org/', null, $context);
```

I guess there should be other php options to fix this problem, when you need to use additional server IP-addresses in outgoing connections.
Feel free to add your answer! ;)

And I will still try to look for non php-based, but OS-based solutions, and will be very-very grateful if someone can describe how I can manage it!